# How can I put this DRY code into a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I am formatting a legend in pyplot, and have successfully gotten the output I want. However, I'm trying to figure out how to format this code into a for loop.

---

This is the code I am trying to loop:

```
L.get_texts()[0].set_text('Global')
L.get_texts()[1].set_text('Bangkok')
L.get_texts()[2].set_text('NYC')
L.get_texts()[3].set_text('Perth')
L.get_texts()[4].set_text('Quito')
L.get_texts()[5].set_text('Santiago')
L.get_texts()[6].set_text('Singapore')
L.get_texts()[7].set_text('Tianjin')
```

I can loop for each index[0,7], but I can't figure out how to loop for the set_text('argument') as well. This is what I have tried so far:

```
legend_labels = ['Global', 'Bangkok', 'NYC', 'Perth', 'Quito', 'Santiago', 
'Singapore', 'Tianjin']

for i in range(8):
L.get_texts()[i].set_text(legend_labels)
```

I made the list, legend_labels, that I want to loop through. I've tried a few different nested for loops, but can't seem to get it working.

From the code that I am trying now this is the output I get:
[Notice only 'Tianjin' gets printed on the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjZfK.png).

This is my desired output: [Each item in list is printed on the legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii5wO.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` that will give you both, the index `i` as well as the label

```
for i, label in enumerate(legend_labels):
    L.get_texts()[i].set_text(label)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to assign the i'th label to the i't text:

```
for i in range(8):
    L.get_texts()[i].set_text(legend_labels[i])
```

More pythonic would be

```
for text, label in zip(L.get_texts(), legend_labels):
    text.set_text(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
legend_labels = ['Global',
                 'Bangkok',
                 'NYC',
                 'Perth',
                 'Quito',
                 'Santiago',
                 'Singapore',
                 'Tianjin'
                 ]

for i in range(8):
    L.get_texts()[i].set_text(legend_labels[i])
```